# Rails searches the mistaken has_and_belongs_to_many table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many

I want to show all types which are related to a specific organisation in a select box of my document form. Types are part of the Ar engine. Organisations are part of another existing engine.

```rb
module Ar
  module OrganisationPatch
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      attr_accessible :ar_document_id

      has_many :ar_documents, :class_name => 'Ar::Document'
      has_and_belongs_to_many :ar_types, :class_name => 'Ar::Type'
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
module Ar
  class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name

    has_many :documents
    has_and_belongs_to_many :organisations
  end
end
```

---

```
class CreateTypeOrganisations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ar_type_organisations, id: false do |t|
      t.uuid :type_id, index: true
      t.uuid :organisation_id, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

In my documents_controller I load types for forms about the before filter. The superior returns the organisation object:

```
def load_form_objects
  unless current_user.admin?
    @types = current_user.superior.ar_types
  else
    @types = Type.all
  end
end
```

Calling the page I get this error and ask me why he is looking for a table called organisations_types:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Ar/documents#new
>
> Mysql2::Error: Table 'portal.organisations_types' doesn't exist:
>   SELECT `ar_types`.* FROM `ar_types` INNER JOIN `organisations_types`
>   ON `ar_types`.`id` = `organisations_types`.`type_id` WHERE
>   `organisations_types`.`organisation_id` =
>   x'891c3986b33845d08d3951645a4f27d5'

Someone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name isn’t map with lexical order what `has_and_belongs_to_many` expect. ( Expected order is `organisations_types` )

So you have to add `:join_table` option in both model's association. Like this,

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :ar_types, :class_name => 'Ar::Type', join_table: "ar_type_organisations"

has_and_belongs_to_many :organisations, join_table: "ar_type_organisations"
```

[Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)